# dompdf Customization Question

Tags: php, zip, dompdf

I'm trying to optimize [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) to do something a bit strange.  As it is on my server, dompdf is generating a pdf file (for the client requesting the file) from a php/html file stored somewhere on the server.  This is cool because it doesn't bog the server down with pdf files, but the problem I have is that I want someone to be able to export a group of PDFs and receive them in a zip file or something similar.

Is there a way to make dompdf export a group of PDF files, based on the filenames of the php/html files, to a zip file or something so the person requesting it can download it?

Let me know if more information is needed.

Thank you!!

Comment: dompdf allows to output the pdf as binary data. You can then add it into a zip and repeat this until you have processed the group of all files.

Comment: Can you export the files in iteration and then just zip them?

Comment: Well as far as I was aware, dompdf doesn't do any exporting, it just converts the files to PDFs on the spot...and I don't want to zip the html files.

Answer (score 1):

DOMPDF only handles a single file at a time. But you could write a PHP script to accept the list of files and then use DOMPDF to parse each one separately. Since DOMPDF can return the rendered PDF as a string you could write each file out to a temporary directory then archive the results when you're done. Or, if you're using dompdf.php you could use exec() to process each HTML document in a similar loop.

Here's a simple example showing one way to do what you want:

```
$files_html = array('docs/file1.html','docs/file2.html');
foreach ($files_html as $file) {
  exec('dompdf.php ' . $file);
}
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('docs/pdfs.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
$files_pdf = glob('docs/*.pdf');
foreach ($files_pdf as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pdfs.zip);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile('docs/pdfs.zip');
```

There are some discussions of using DOMPDF to batch process files in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dompdf/wlOlKxB2ajM/discussion) and [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=225).